# Error when extending an angular framework class RouteReuseStrategy

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

There are two aspects of my question. The error to solve is, when I use custom route reuse strategy the strategy does not get triggerred when I use implements to override angular router class RouteReuseStrategy and when I use extends keyword I get the below exception,

UMSClient:32 Error: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
        at setPrototypeOf ()
        at __extends (http://localhost:8000/app/UMSClient/com/ipc/ums/modules/shared/CustomRouteReuse.service.js:8:13)
        at eval (http://localhost:8000/app/UMSClient/com/ipc/ums/modules/shared/CustomRouteReuse.service.js:35:17)
        at execute (http://localhost:8000/app/UMSClient/com/ipc/ums/modules/shared/CustomRouteReuse.service.js:54:14)
    Error loading http://localhost:8000/app/main.js

```
import { RouteReuseStrategy,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,DetachedRouteHandler} 
from '@angular/router';

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy extends RouteReuseStrategy {

shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean { return false; }

store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, detachedTree: DetachedRouteHandle): void {}

shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean { return false; }

retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle { return null ; }

shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log("inside shouldReuseRoute...");
  return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig ;
}
```

}

I have a feeling this is related to my compilation and build strategy. I use a framework developed before me in gulp and system js. When I copy the app to webpack based angular cli, there is no issue and route strategy gets triggered properly.

Details of my build setup:

- using gulp to compile

  gulp.task("compile", () => {
    let tsResult = gulp.src("app/**/*.ts")
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write(".", {sourceRoot: '/app'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("build/app"));
    });
- the package json is,

  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~4.3.1",

  "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.1",

  "@angular/core": "~4.3.1",

  "@angular/forms": "~4.3.1",

  "@angular/http": "~4.3.1",

  "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.1",

  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.1",

  "@angular/router": "~4.3.1",

  "@angular/upgrade": "~4.3.1",

  "@angular2-material/tabs": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",

  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.9",

  "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",

  "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",

  "core-js": "^2.4.1",

  "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16-11",

  "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",

  "ng2-datetime-picker": "^0.9.8",

  "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",

  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",

  "rxjs": "^5.2.0",

  "systemjs": "^0.20.19",

  "tsd": "^0.6.5",

  "underscore": "^1.8.3",

  "zone.js": "^0.8.5"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

  "concurrently": "^3.5.1",

  "del": "^3.0.0",

  "gulp": "^3.9.1",

  "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.1",

  "gulp-tslint": "^8.1.2 ",

  "gulp-typescript": "^3.2.3",

  "lite-server": "^2.2.2",

  "tslint": "~5.8.0",

  "typescript": "~2.6.1",

  "typings": "^2.1.1",

  "ts-node": "~3.3.0"

tsconfig.json:

{

```
"compilerOptions": {

"outDir": "build/app",

"target": "es5",

"module": "system",

"moduleResolution": "node",

"sourceMap": true,

"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

"experimentalDecorators": true,

"removeComments": false,

"noImplicitAny": false

},

 "exclude": [

"gulpfile.ts",

"node_modules"
```

]
}

My specific question is, I dont know what related dependency is causing this run time exception. Somebody with knowledge of gulp build procedure, please guide me to get the issue sorted out.

I browsed stack overflow for the solution to this exception. Every discussion indicates that there is some issue in the order of class hierarchy and in my case, I am using the angular framework class which 100% works fine in webpack angular cli project.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my workspace structure. I updated package.json to use angular version 4.3.0 and ran npm install to download it to node_modules folder. But gulp build was reading from another node_modules folder and it was reading angular 2 version causing the issue. When I update the actual node_modules folder with angular 4 version, the customRouteReuseStrategy started working.

Thanks,